# how to run ceiling joists across a 15' room with no ceiling

Tags: ceiling, joists

removed some metal T system drop ceilings now I want sheetrock but not sure best way to run ceiling joists across 15' room if I go with 8' 2x4 how do I tie them together towards center of room to prevent slag ***Edit*** if room is only like 14' can I just run a 15' 2x4 across span of room or do I have to buy engineered joists even though only weight I'll be making them hold is sheetrock

Comment: Have you looked at the relevant building codes to see what they require? Typically there are requirements stating what size lumber to use as joists for a given span, and how the walls the ends rest on must be constructed (load-bearing walls). Hint: 2x4 will _never_ be an acceptable joist size.

Comment: no nothing is load bearing it's on a first story literally only weight it'll have to take is the sheetrock being attached to it... I'm just curious as what is the best way to mend 2x8s together at meeting points in wide room or should i just go with longer 2x4s

Comment: You can't span that with less than engineered joists. You can shorten the span with intermediate connections to the existing ceiling, though. Edit your post to add more information about the structure. There's not enough to provide an answer.

Comment: @isherwood https://youtu.be/W_QmhB5aDGI at about 6:25 of this video the sane way this guy ceiling looks is how mines looks.. except my room is wider than 8' trying to figure best way to mend 2x4s together to span about a 13' gap or should I just buy 15' 2x4s

Comment: @user80572 do NOT use 2x4s for this purpose and do NOT try to "mend" joists in the middle. You will be _very_ sorry later on if you do. As in, "ceiling fell on my head" sorry. You really need to look up the relevant building codes for this and follow them.

Comment: I don't understand your response to my comment. It's as though you didn't even read what I wrote.

Comment: Is this in a basement like in the video?

Comment: @isherwood I'm so sorry read your comment this morning.. I know I can use engineered joists to span that distance but can't I just use 15' 2x4s I'm only attaching sheetrock to it not like it'll ever be taking any weight.... maybe I'm making my question clear enough but everyone here seems to be dodging my question lol... I just wanna know if I can use long 2x4s with 2x4 joist hangars to span the distance

Comment: @alfreema no it's ground level and there is no 2nd story to my house.... I wanna know thoughts if I could use a few 15' 2x4s every 16" to span the distance or do I have to stick with engineered joists I'm only attaching sheetrock to ceiling *Only sheetrock* no 2nd story and I won't be putting anything into attic ever I have a shed for that

Comment: There is no need to keep saying "Only Sheetrock"  We get it.  And we're asking questions that you're not answering.

Comment: The correct answer is: NO.  And that is based on CODE.  We will not give you an answer that justifies your design no matter how much you say "But it's only".  We do our best to give you a code compliant answer.  Should you choose to NOT follow code, that's on you. We will not tell you it's ok.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore what questions are you asking that I wasn't answering any questions I'll try best to answer... not at all trying to make you guys give wrong or not up to code answers was just curious what were joist requirements for a 14'' span

Comment: @ChrisCudmore ok I appreciate this answer it's what I wanted to know... could I span 2x4 across a 14' area... I guess no because of slag

Comment: The use of the term joist is confusing the issue.  Joists are for supporting a floor or ceiling, **If** you had a suspended ceiling than presumably it was suspended **from something** and that something is still in place and you want to cover it with Sheetrock, not build new structure. Perhaps you need to ad furring strips to attach the new Sheetrock to?  WHAT KIND OF CEILING/STRUCTURE DO YOU HAVE NOW?  *Please explain your situation better and be very descriptive as to what your actual space is and how it is constructed*.

Comment: @Alaskaman I wish there was a way for me to attach a pic I'm new to this app... I also don't mean to be disparaging to anyone replying to me I've been really appreciating every response....very insightful stuff...... description of room... ok imagine it's a 1 story house and in this room ceiling is now missing and when I look up all I see is rafters... 4 square walls and no ceiling everything is solid no current structure problems... the room is rectangular like 14x11.... 4 square brick walls rafters and roof above but no ceiling currently in interior because of metal drop ceiling tear out

Comment: @Alaskaman Sorry I referred to ceiling studs as joists just figured any planks running  across room floor or ceiling were joists... I guess I should've said... "Can I run 2x4s as studs across my 14' span room ceiling and attach sheetrock to it".... but now I plan to wrap a band of treated 2x6s to the brick with concrete anchors... then running 2x6s in hangars across room ceiling  as studs... will also run and tie planks in across tops of 2x6s to reinforce... I doubt this will sag but wonder it will hold sheetrock... I feel paranoid now lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To span 14' or more with a ceiling joist with an uninhabited attic with no storage, [you need 2x6s or larger](http://constructitall.com/9-uncategorised/972-maximum-span-calculations-for-joists-a-rafters.html).  If you want something smaller, you need an engineeered product rated for the span.

Comment: Thx so much for answer!!!! I went with 2x6 for joists before on another Diy but was curious why not 2x4s but I guess 2x4s across that span is a no go... was just curious....  But everyone's replies were really insightful I will still read and interact with any new comments because I find this really useful

Comment: Have you picked up a #2. 2×4 lately? When I built my last shop back in 2000 I used 2×6 and some of those scared me (were taken back) hold the 2x4 at 1 end and flex it you would be surprised how many snap now add a hundred pounds of sheetrock and mud it is just asking to fail this is why everyone said no.

Comment: @EdBeal I deal with 2x4s alot I just figured they had better sheer strength then that judging by all the replies I'm more than likely mistaken lol